# Swift protocol conformance causes segmentation fault 11

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have a simple custom protocol so a type can be represented as an Int like this:

```
public protocol IntegerRepresentable {
  var integerValue: Int { get }
}
```

and have Int to extend this protocol like

```
extension Int: IntegerRepresentable {

  public var integerValue: Int {
    return self
  }
}
```

When I make use of this code in this example it throws a segmentation fault 11 error:

```
protocol P {
  typealias I: IntegerRepresentable
}

struct S: P {
  typealias I = Int
}
```

I have no idea why is this failing, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code compiles and runs just fine for me. Can you give more details about your environment? Can you double-check that an app with _only_ that code fails for you?

Comment: It runs only if all the code is in the same file, otherwise it throws the error. Just realized that

Comment: Is there any way to fix that behavior?

Comment: Keep it all in one file.   Try it in the current Xcode beta. If the issue persists there, file a bug.

Comment: It is actually in the current Beta, I had the beta 3 and downloaded the fourth for the sole purpose of trying to fix this issue. How is the process of bug filing?

Comment: Do you want me to file it for you?

Comment: If it's not much trouble. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I've been testing a little more. The segfault arises only if the extension to Int and the typealias resolution are in different files. That isn't completely unreasonable, I guess, because the extension must execute before the typealias resolution can work (i.e., we need to know that Int _is_ an IntegerRepresentable). It's still a bug, of course; any segfault while compiling is a bug.

Comment: So then it could be a matter of hierarchy at the moment of going through the files resulting in a compiler side bug?

Comment: Or something. I can't help noticing that the segfault is in a routine called `swift::ModuleFile::maybeReadConformance`, called during the MergeSwiftModule phase. This suggests that the problem is that we are not discovering in a coherent way that Int _is_ indeed an IntegerRepresentable. - The radar is filed (20456758) so we'll see if anything comes of it. At least you have a workaround.

Comment: Maybe that's why something like moving the extension was enough to silent that fault. Thanks a lot, hope they fix that soon.

Comment: I have just run in to this myself and I think you've saved me a lot of time! You can add the extension to your class in its own file, but omit the actual protocol from it (e.g. `extension Int { ... }`) and then in the file that uses the typealias add it (e.g. `extension Int: IntegerRepresentable {}`)